# Sufficient Statistic and Unbiased Estimate in Exponential Family

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, fisher-information, rao-blackwell

I am reading this [classic paper (Information and the Accuracy Attainable in the Estimation of Statistical Parameters)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0919-5_16) by CR Rao where he deals with sufficient statistics in exponential distributions building on Koopman's work (eqs 3.11-3.12).

An exponential distribution $\phi(x,\theta)$ is given by 
$$
\phi(x, \theta)=\exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right)
$$ 
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are functions of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ are functions of $\theta$

We can derive the expecatation $E(X_1)$ and variance $Var(X_1)$ easily as follows 
\begin{align}
\int \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right) & d x_{i}=1  \; \; \text{(differentiating on both sides) }\\
\int X_1 \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right) d x_{i} d \Theta_1 + & \int \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right)  d x_{i} d \Theta_2 = 0 \\
\implies E\left(X_{1}\right)&=-\frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}} \\ 
\int X_1 \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right) d x_{i} & = -\frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}} \; \; \text{(differentiating on both sides again) }\\
\int X_1^2 \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right) d x_{i} \frac{d \Theta_{1}}{d \theta} + & \int X_1 \exp \left(\Theta_{1} X_{1}+\Theta_{2}+X_{2}\right) d x_{i} \frac{d \Theta_{2}} {d \theta} \\  =& -\frac{d}{d \theta} (\frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}}) \\
E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 = - \frac{\frac{d}{d \theta} (\frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}})}{\frac{d \Theta_1}{d \theta}} & = - \frac{d^2 \Theta_2}{d \Theta_1^2}
\end{align}

> The author claims that $X_1$ is the best unbiased estimate of $-\frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}}$ and
>   proves it as follows:

$$
\left\{\frac{d}{d \theta} \frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}}\right\}^{2} /\left\{\frac{d^{2} \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}^{2}} \frac{d \Theta_{1}}{d \theta}\right\}=-\frac{d^{2} \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}^{2}}=V\left(X_{1}\right) \; \; \qquad\text{(1)}
$$

I am able to follows this step only partially. We know that the generalized CRLB is given as $$
V(t) \ge \left\{f^{\prime}(\theta)\right\}^{2} / I
$$
where $t$ is the unbiased estimate of some function $f(\theta)$ instead of $\theta$. Therefore, the numerator $\left\{\frac{d}{d \theta} \frac{d \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}}\right\}^{2}$ follows. I am not sure how the denominator and further simplification follows in equation (1). Possible Errata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the paper. The denominator should be $-\left\{\frac{d^{2} \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}^{2}} \left( \frac{d \Theta_{1}}{d \theta} \right)^2\right\}$.

It is obtained as follows:

\begin{align}
I & = \Bbb E\left( \left( \frac{d (\Theta_1X_1 + \Theta_2) }{d \theta} \right)^2 \right) \\
& = \Bbb E \left(  X^2 ( \frac{d \Theta_1}{ d \theta})^2 + 2X \frac{d \Theta_1}{ d \theta} \frac{d \Theta_2}{ d \theta} + (\frac{d \Theta_2}{ d \theta})^2 \right) \\
& \qquad \text{Substituting the expectation.}\\
& = \Bbb E \left(  X^2 ( \frac{d \Theta_1}{ d \theta})^2  - (\frac{d \Theta_2}{ d \theta})^2 \right) \\ 
& \qquad \text{Substituting the second moment.} \\
& = \left( ( \frac{d^2 \Theta_1}{ d \Theta_1^2}+ ( \frac{d \Theta_2}{ d \Theta_1})^2)  ( \frac{d \Theta_1}{ d \theta})^2  - (\frac{d \Theta_2}{ d \theta})^2 \right) \\ 
& = - \frac{d^{2} \Theta_{2}}{d \Theta_{1}^{2}} \left( \frac{d \Theta_{1}}{d \theta} \right)^2
\end{align}